# ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert Firebase `TimeStamp` into JavaScript date.

I referred this link to convert Javascript object to Javascript date,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

**Firestore timestamp (From API):**

```
"time": {
       "_seconds": 1563620755,
        "_nanoseconds": 688000000
 }
```

Before saving `time` into cloud firestore I've to convert it to JavaScript `Date()`.

So I used below code to convert object into Date.

```
let data = request.body
let tiemStamp = new Timestamp(data.time._seconds,data.time._nanoseconds)
```

But I got below error,

> ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined

How do to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `Timestamp` is under `firebase.firestore` namespace (or in Javascripts case object), you might want to use it as follows:

```js
let tiemStamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(data.time._seconds,data.time._nanoseconds)
```

```js
console.log(new firebase.firestore.Timestamp());
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I error `ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined` Am I need to import anything? Right now I have `firebase-functions` & `firebase-admin`

Comment: @Aishu `import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';` should be enough in nodejs, you can  then access it like `firestore.Timestamp`

Comment: Yes, it's seems solving problem by using VSCode. But I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` while deploy.

Comment: I don't know why it throws the error, you could try `import firestore from 'firebase-admin'`

Comment: `new admin.firestore.TimeStamp` is worked.. thanks!